# tableau server Trusted Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory, tableau-api

I have a problem with my embedded tableau server, I am trying to embed a tableau server visualisation using (tableau server + node.js + Active directory), everything works well except the final step, where I can't see the viz on my web browser.
when I click on the tableau server button it show me a popup, but when I enter my credentials to sign in, i can't see the vizualisation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6YxD.png)

```js
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const querystring = require('querystring');


function processApiResponse(res, tableauServer, username, site) {
    let url = new URL(tableauServer + '/trusted');
    let body = {
        username: username
    };
    if (site) {
        body['target_site'] = site;
    }

    let postData = querystring.stringify(body);
    console.log(' => POST ' + url + ' ' + postData);

    let module = http;
    if (url.protocol === 'https:') {
        module = https;
    }

    let req = module.request({
        method: 'POST',
        hostname: url.hostname,
        path: '/trusted',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }, function (tableauServerResponse) {
        let ticketData = '';
        tableauServerResponse.on('data', function (chunk) {
            ticketData += chunk;
        });

        tableauServerResponse.on('end', function () {
            let contents = JSON.stringify(
                {
                    ticket: ticketData
                });
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.end(contents + '\n');
            console.log('200 POST /api - ' + contents);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function (error) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
    });

    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
}

function processRequest(req, callback) {
    let chunks = [];
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', () => {
        let body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();
        callback(querystring.parse(body));
    });
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   if (req.method === 'GET') {
       if (req.url === '/') {
           let contents = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'ascii');
           res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
           res.end(contents);
           console.log('200 GET / - ' + contents.length);
       } else {
           res.writeHead(404);
           res.end('Not Found');
           console.log('404 GET ' + req.url);
       }
   } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
       if (req.url === '/api') {
           processRequest(req, function (data) {
               let site = null;
               console.log(' => ' + JSON.stringify(data));

               let url = new URL(data['share_link']);
               if (url.pathname.startsWith('/t/')) {
                   let tokens = url.pathname.split('/');
                   site = tokens[2];
               }

               processApiResponse(res, url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname, data['username'], site);
           });
       } else {
           res.writeHead(404);
           res.end('Not Found');
           console.log('404 POST ' + req.url);
       }
   } else {
       res.writeHead(405);
       res.end('Invalid request method: ' + req.method);
   }
}).listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>trusted_auth_demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 2em">
        <form id="form" action="/api">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="share_link">Share Link:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="share_link" name="share_link" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 2em">
        <pre id="response">
        </pre>
    </div>

    <div class="container text-center" id="containerDiv">
    </div>

    <script>
        document.forms['form'].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            fetch(event.target.action, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(event.target))
            }).then(function (res) {
                return res.json();
            }).then(function (body) {
                document.getElementById("response").innerText = JSON.stringify(body);

                if (body.ticket === '-1') {
                    return;
                }
                let url = new URL(document.getElementById('share_link').value);
                url.pathname = '/trusted/' + body.ticket + url.pathname;

                let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                iframe.src = url.href;
                iframe.width = '800px';
                iframe.height = '600px';

                document.getElementById("containerDiv").appendChild(iframe);
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6YxD.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: He has a node API with a button that redirects to TableauSoftware API with some parameters. Then he want to display the result in a iframe on the web page.
But TableauSoftware API requires authentication and once authenticated is not redirected as he would like.
In `function (tableauServerResponse)` you should probably handle a `401` answer then wait for a successful authentication before being able to request the desired URL.
This waiting part is probably the harder ...